# Unable to pass State in React Router link

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

My target is really simple, i want to pass a param from one page to another by using Link state:

Sender Page:

```js
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
...
<Link className="start" to={{pathname: "/game", state: {string: "something to pass"}}}>
       clickme
</Link>
...
```

Reciever Page:

```js
import {Link, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
.....
let location = useLocation();
....
```

But console.log(location) keeps showing me an empty state:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it on this way

Just seperate "to" from "state"

Now it may be too late for your problem, but maybe it will help someone else

```
<Link className="start" 
      to={pathname: "/game"} 
      state={string: "something to pass"}>
      clickme
</Link>
```

Comment: // Little Correction
to={{ pathname: "/game" }}
state={{ string: "something to pass" }}

Answer (score -1):

I mentioned both old and new way to get state using useLocation.
When you click on User link ,you will get your string and state will not be null.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-uselocation-hooks-forked-0ld0m?file=/package.json:209-237